# Converting Grayscale values from .csv to BufferedImage

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm attempting to convert a .csv file containing grayscale values to an image using BufferedImage.
The csv is read into `pixArray[]` initially, in which all values are doubles.

I am attempting to use BufferedImage to create a 100x100px output image with the code

```
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.
                    TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    image.setRGB(x, y, (int)Math.round(pixArray[y]));
                }
            }

            File file_out = new File("output.png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", file_out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but all I have as output is a 100x100 black square.

I've tried alternatives to `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` with no success, as well as the png format for outout, and can't find what is producing this error.

Comment: Show a sample of the input data.  If the values are `0.0<= x <= 1` then the `Math.round()` is truncating everything to zero, which would be black.

Comment: Values are all 0<= x <= 255
Initially they are read in as ex: `111.8884 112.2339 113.4165` hence the casting.
I've tried removing the rounding and kept the 'int' casting, and still received all black as output.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `int g = (int)Math.round(pixArray[y]); image.setRGB(x,y,new Color(g,g,g).getRGB());`  I think what you are doing is setting the alpha to the pixel value but leaving the color components all zero.

Comment: This worked perfectly, don't know how I didn't realize. Thank you.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer so future searchers will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
int g = (int)Math.round(pixArray[y]); 
image.setRGB(x,y,new Color(g,g,g).getRGB());
```

What your current code is doing is setting the alpha to the pixel value but leaving the color components all zero.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an alternative solution. While Jim's answer is correct and works, it is also one of the slowest* ways to put sample values into a gray scale `BufferedImage`.

A `BufferedImage` with `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` don't need all the conversion to and from RGB colors. To put the gray values directly into the image, do it through the image's raster:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) { 
    int value = (int) Math.round(pixArray[y])

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         raster.setSample(x, y, 0, value);
    }
}
```

---

*) Slow because of creating excessive throw-away `Color` instances, but mostly due to color space conversion to/from sRGB color space. Probably not very noticeable in a 100x100 image, but if you try 1000x1000 or larger, you will notice.

PS: I also re-arranged the loops to loop over x in the inner loop. This is normally faster, especially when reading values, due to data locality and caching in modern CPUs. In your case, it matters mostly because you only need to compute (round, cast) the value for each row.